# Standalone GCC for build tools repository

Tags: gcc, build

I would like to have a tools repository structured like so:

```
tools
|-- gnu
|   `-- gcc
|       |-- 4.6.0
|       `-- 4.6.2
|--  microsoft
|    `-- stylecop
|        `-- 4.6.2.0
...
```

So that every developer across the company has the same tools during the build process.

Is it possible to create a 'build jail' in this way?

I don't know how to get the GNU tool-chain into a repository this way?

Does anyone have any experience with this?  I've heard of `chroot` build jails.

I have a requirement to build on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Debian (and thereby Ubuntu) people have developed the excellent [`pbuilder`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto) package for such issues. It originally creates a tarball with a minimal Debian environment that is unpacked into a chroot, but can easily be adapted for your requirements.